# java Mongo DB update field on condition

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and I am performing an update Many to update several records in one operation

```
UpdateResult result = collection.updateMany(query, update);
```

The update field is defined like this

```
Bson update = Updates.combine(
            Updates.set(field1, 1),
            Updates.set(field2, 2);
```

But now I want to define a conditional update for field3. if `field3 == null` then `field3=3`

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use the update call. Instead, you must use an aggregation pipeline, because that is where $cond is available.

```
BasicDBList compareList = new BasicDBList();
compareList.add(null);
compareList.add("$field3");

collection.aggregate(List.of(
                query,
                new BasicDBObject()
                        .append("$set", new BasicDBObject("field3",
                                new BasicDBObject("$cond",
                                        new BasicDBObject("if",
                                                new BasicDBObject("$eq", compareList))
                                                .append("then", 3)
                                                .append("else", "$field3")))
                                .append("field1", 1)
                                .append("field2", 2)),
                merge(collectionName))).first();
```

I suspect that there is also a way with the ConditionalOperators class instead of BasicDBObject (still using the aggregation pipeline), but I do not have the time to investigate at the moment.